# SQL Syntax Query

Tags: sqlite, syntax

Can anyone advise where i'm going wrong with the syntax here please?

I have this query which returns 26 rows

```
SELECT firstname, lastname
  FROM author 
  WHERE authorid IN (
  SELECT authorid
  FROM written_by
  JOIN book ON written_by.bookdescid = book.bookdescid
  WHERE UPPER (book.title) LIKE UPPER ('%electric%')
  AND NOT UPPER (written_by.role) LIKE UPPER('%translator%'));
```

This appears to be correct and the reason I am using UPPER and ('%example%') like this is for variations in capitalization.

However, when I try and add into the query to also pick up where the book subtitle also includes 'electric' I am somehow getting the syntax wrong as it returns less rows? If anything it should be the same or more... I've tried a few variations but this one below is what i thought would work..

```
SELECT firstname, lastname
  FROM author 
  WHERE authorid IN (
  SELECT authorid
  FROM written_by
  JOIN book ON written_by.bookdescid = book.bookdescid
  WHERE UPPER (book.title) OR (book.subtitle) LIKE UPPER ('%electric%')
  AND NOT UPPER (written_by.role) LIKE UPPER('%translator%'));
```

Comment: What do you think that does & why? If you try to justify your expectations according to (authoritative) documentation (or, as a beginner, even an introduction) you would find you can't. One should always read the manual for functionality one is using. OR takes 2 conditions & has lower precedence than LIKE. PS For code questions a [mre] is expected. Which includes expectations with justification. Also minmal code with the problem like `select * from t where x or y like 'A'` would show the problem is OR vs LIKE. Or OR vs = even smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use separate expressions with the operator `LIKE`:

```
  WHERE ((UPPER(book.title) LIKE '%ELECTRIC%') OR (UPPER(book.subtitle) LIKE '%ELECTRIC%'))
  AND (UPPER(written_by.role) NOT LIKE '%TRANSLATOR%');
```

Also use `UPPER()` only for the columns and provide the string literals in uppercase.